# How can I create a global object that is accessible in all the MVC & WEB API after it start and load information from file

Tags: c#, singleton, global-asax

I have a class that have a dictionaries that isbeing being load from local XML from App_Data. Where should I add that class to make it global and visible to all the controller in my application? I just one that the behave like a singleton. If a good option to add that in global.asax

Class example

```
  public class OptionsNames
        {
            private Dictionary<int, string> names;

            public OptionsNames()
            {

                names = new Dictionary<int, string>();

                names= LoadOptionsFromXML();

            }

            public string GetNameById(int id)
            {
                if (names.ContainsKey(id))
                     return names[id];

                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Comment: u caan declare it in Application_Start()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a `static` object:

```
public static class OptionsNames
{
    private static Dictionary<int, string> names;

    static OptionsNames()
    {
        names = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        names = LoadOptionsFromXML();
    }

    public static string GetNameById(int id)
    {
        if (names.ContainsKey(id))
             return names[id];
        return string.Empty;
    }

    // other class members
}
```

It doesn't really matter *where* the static class is located, it can be referenced from anywhere.  Just make sure it's located in an intuitive location/namespace.

Consuming code would simply invoke it directly without having to create an instance:

```
var name = OptionsNames.GetNameById(someIdValue);
```

Comment: This could work but my question how the class will behave related to the  names = LoadOptionsFromXML(); As static class is a read file on Disk only happen one time? Also If I want this configurable cannot add a parameter to my static ctor.

Comment: @Devsined: If `LoadOptionsFromXML` is also static then this will work.  That's not specified in the question, but I don't see why it couldn't be static.  This approach would load the file once per instance of the application.  If the file changes, you'd either need to trigger a re-start of the application or add an operation to re-load from the file (which could perhaps be triggered from some administrative interface).

Answer (score 2):

This is a singleton example with lazy loading

```
public class OptionsNames
{
    private static Dictionary<int, string> names;

    private static readonly Lazy<OptionsNames> LazyInstance = new Lazy<OptionsNames>(() => new OptionsNames());

    protected OptionsNames()
    {
        names = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        names = LoadOptionsFromXML();
    }

    public static OptionsNames Instance
    {
        get { return LazyInstance.Value; }
    }

    public static string GetNameById(int id)
    {
        if (names.ContainsKey(id))
             return names[id];
        return string.Empty;
    }        
}
```

And you dont need to do anything in global.asax, just call this way

```
var name = OptionsNames.Instance.GetNameById(someIdValue);
```

That's it.

Comment: thanks. what I am looking for is load the information from the file only one time with this solution every time that I use the class I will to a read on disk operation.

Comment: @Devsined you need to learn about caching. You don't need global object in this case.

Comment: @Devsined please read about lazy loading and singleton in .net. This will load only once, is an implementation if the singleton pattern. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx